Complete quadrangle $ABCD$; line $r$

Consider the complete quadrangle $ABCD$ and a line $r$ that doesn't pass through any of these points. $X= r \cap AB; Y= r \cap AC; Z=r \cap AD; T=r \cap BC; U=r \cap BD, V= R \cap  CD$ and $X',Y',Z',T',U',V'$ their respective harmonic conjugates with respect to the pairs $(A,B), (A,C), (A,D), (B,C), (B,D), (C,D)$.

My goal is to show that $X'V'; U'Y'; Z'T'$ are concurrent. Firstly for a given triangle $ABC; X \in BC; Y \in AC; Z \in AB$; $X',Y',Z$ are colinear; where $X',Y'$ are respective harmonic conjugates of the points $X,Y$ with respect to $(B,C),(A,C)$.
With this last result, I can identify $X'Z' \cap T'V'=U; U'T' \cap Z'Y'=V, \dots $ but I couldn't figure out how to use this result to show that $X'V'; U'Y'; Z'T'$ are concurrent.
Should I use the harmonic conjugate of $U$ wrt to $(Z',X')$ and wrt to $(V',T')$?

Hello. It would seem reasonable to me to propose a drawing, wouldn't it?

What you say is true but I think you're on the wrong track. If $r$ is the line at infinity, then X',Y',... are middles and you come across the configuration of the tetrahedron where the result becomes trivial.

https://www.geogebra.org/classic/dbvtxcwz
